# Filter string from IEnumerable list C# linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a IEnumerable object, It's contains,

FirstName
LastName
Description
Price

I want to filter this IEnumerable list by description property, Which contains "there object reference errors with no way to fix". By this string.

Is it possible to write LINQ Query for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide some *examples* of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible in LINQ to do that and much more:

```
var result = myIEnumerable.Where(d => d.Description == "there object reference errors with no way to fix");
```

Comment: I think your query is OK but i need to compare the string, Similar to "Like" keyword in SQL. not directly equal to the text field.

Sample string would be like this : "there object reference errors with no way to fix.ApplicationServices.ApplicationService`1.<TryExecute>d__2`1.MoveNext()"

Comment: @SithijaSahan, Then simply change == to Contains(). Contains is translated for SQL as LIKE. BTW please ask your questions more clearly.